# ArrayFormula to transfer items in a column from one google sheet to a column in another google sheet ignoring blank cells

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

I'm trying to transfer items in a column from one google sheet to a column in another google sheet ignoring blank cells entirely.
I have this formula that will transfer all cells including the blanks:
=ARRAYFORMULA(FormResponses1!C:C)
I also have this formula that does the same substituting the blanks with the word "hello":
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(FormResponses1!A:A="","",IF(ISBLANK(FormResponses1!C:C),"hello",FormResponses1!C:C)))

I'm trying to transfer the non-blank cells to the other sheet ignoring the blank cells altogether, making a column with 5 cells as opposed to 7 cells as below
The column being transferred from the original sheet looks like this:

1. Apple
2. Peach
3. (Blank cell)
4. Orange
5. (Blank cell)
6. Grape
7. Cherry

I need the new sheet to look like this without any blank cells in the column:

1. Apple
2. Peach
3. Orange
4. Grape
5. Cherry

I can't seem to find a way to do it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Neal

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

##### FILTER Function

[FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197) Returns a filtered version of the source range, returning only rows or columns that meet the specified conditions.
**Syntax:** `=FILTER(range, condition1, [condition2, ...])`

##### Formula

```
=FILTER(FormResponses1!C:C,FormResponses1!C:C<>"")
```

**Source**
[image]

**Destination**
[image]